# How can I use my CNN model features to train a Extreme Learning Machine Model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, conv-neural-network, tf.keras

I have a CNN model implemented using python to classify an image dataset. Now I want to use the features from this model in an Extreme Learning Machine (EML) model. How can I extract the features from my CNN model and later use them for the EML model?
My CNN Model code is:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(200,200,3)),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2,2),
    #
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2,2),
    #
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2,2),
    ##
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    ##
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    ##
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Extreme machine learning model"? Can you provide an example?

Comment: It's a single-layer neural network that takes features of any existing models. You can get better intuitions from this paper: http://www.di.unito.it/~cancelli/retineu11_12/ELM-NC-2006.pdf